# Restore the initial styling for :focus if outline is set to 0?

Tags: css

Im loading a video player which hides the :focus style by setting the outline to 0. I need to override this with my CSS to bring back the default browser styling for focused elements. Is there a cross browser way to do this?

This works in Chrome but not Firefox:

```
  outline: initial;
  outline-style: auto;
```

I need to support Chrome, Firefox and recent versions of IE at the very least. Devices will load the video in full screen so dont need the styling to work for this.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**
i dont think firefox recognizes `outline-style: auto;`

```
outline:initial;
outline-style: initial;
```

OLD:

isnt it possible to just apply `outline-style: none;` on `:focus` and then when it loses focus, it'll return to its original outline automatically without needed to do `outline-style: auto;`?

```css
.focusMe:focus {
    outline-style: none;
    color: gray;
}
.focusMe {
    outline-style: dashed;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="focusMe">THIS IS DIV THING</a>
```

Comment: We might be talking at cross purposes. Im loading a 3rd party video player meaning that I cant edit the HTML or CSS thats there already. This CSS sets outline: 0; to hide the focus state of the buttons. What I need is to bring back the default focus state.

Comment: The code in my answer does this for Chrome, but I cant see how to do this for Firefox.

Comment: try `outline-style: initial;` instead of `auto`

Comment: ahh, sorry then, dev sites say that theres compatibility for `initial` in firefox 1.5 and up. gl